# Firebase is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an Angular project and use Firebase, and it's erroring with `ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined`, but I can not figure out why.

[image]

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My Contacts App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>myContacts</h1>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="contacts/contacts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my contact.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myContacts.contacts', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
    controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://<my_project_name>.firebaseio.com/contacts');

  $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref);
  console.log($scope.contacts);
}]);
```

my app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myContacts', [
  'ngRoute',
  'firebase',
  'myContacts.contacts'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/contacts'});
}]);
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.1",
    "protractor": "^3.2.2",
    "shelljs": "^0.6.0",
    "firebase": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",

    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app",

    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",

    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",

    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",

    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + sed(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/,'sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map','app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

In package.json file I firebase assigned "*", I do not know if it can do it? Everything else looks good...

[firebase from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jhl8.png)

this is bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-loader": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.0",
    "html5-boilerplate": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

whether there might have to give Firebase?

Comment: Are there any other errors on the console? In particular, did the `firebase.js` from bower components load? Can you access `Firebase` object from the console? It looks like you are using `bower` as your dependency manager and may need to run `bower install`. The other option is to move to `npm` (and `node_modules` from `bower_components`) and run `npm install` with your given `package.json`.

Comment: no any other errors, and can be accessed firebase from console, I do not know what could be the problem ...

Comment: Is there anything in your `index.html` which may include the `contacts.js` file _before_ `firebase.js` is loaded? Also, though you can access `firebase` object, can you also access the `Firebase` constructor on the console?

Comment: I don't know how access the Firebase constructor on the console?

Comment: Upgrade to firebase 3.x

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue.. awful experience..

Eventually, found this: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

[image]

Comment: I have this particular issue and am using the method outlined here, but with the same error, so it appears there may be an alternative underlying cause.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you're getting the latest version of Firebase (3 and up) which doesn't work with the Firebase constructor [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). You're getting it because in your `package.json` you added `firebase: "*"`

You should initialize as others suggested and before any work with firebase is done. This could be someplace global, or in some config block (angular's). 
After initialization you can get a database reference using

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

With the new Firebase version, you need to use a compatible AngularFire version, so you'll need it to be above 2 (confusing versioning, I know), which you can find documentation for in their [GitHub page](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/README.md).

Didn't see AngularFire at all in your `package.json` nor in your `bower.json` but if you're working with Firebase 3.x.x then you'll need AngularFire 2.x.x

Answer (score 1):

`"firebase": "*"` in your `package.json` will install the latest firebase `^3.1.0` which is not compatible with firebase `2.4.2`.

The new documentation is in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)

To include and configure firebase in your index.html:

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>


  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
    var config = {
        apiKey: "your apiKey from firebase website",
        authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
      };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

</script>
```

You can auto-generate the config above in https://console.firebase.google.com/ by creating a new project.

Comment: and then what? How do you get to `new Firebase()` ?  it is still undefined

Comment: And then you don't need `new Firebase()`. You can get a reference with `firebase.database().ref()`

Answer (score 0):

Either one of the following configuration can help you.

1) You can include the following in your script tag of index.html

src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"

2) or you can include the following in app.module.ts

import * as firebase from "firebase";

Second syntax is better as you are not hard coding any version information.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your firebase project/app console.
   [Firebase app console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPSM2.png)
2. Click "Add Firebase to your web app"
3. Then you will be given some script. 
   [Firebase initialization script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcVNC.png)
   Add those to your project script before using the Firebase.

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

In case of a hosting project the catch is that local script files are loading before Firebase. To prevent that, simply load them 'deferred', like this:

```
<script defer src="app.js"></script>
```

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56265925/2743201) by [Paul De Jong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214698/paul-de-jong)!