# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create Google authentication but I copy `var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();` to my JavaScript and it keeps telling me that `Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`.

Here is my code:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

function signin(){

  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  var user = result.user;

}).catch(function(error) {

  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  var email = error.email;
  var credential = error.credential;

}); 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this error because `firebase` variable has not been instantiated and initialized on the page on which you are running the code. To do so you need to -

1. Include the relevant scripts-

   `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>`

`firebase.js` contains the variable `firebase` representing your firebase app. `firebase-auth.js` contains the `firebase.auth` library which your code is using.

2. Initialize your app using -

   ```
   var config = {
       apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
       authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
       storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
   };

   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   ```

To learn more refer - https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: sure i will may i ask is there any way to contact you please like a gmail or other .......

Comment: including both these scripts will give an uncaught exception: auth: Firebase: Firebase service named 'auth' already registered (app/duplicate-service)... just including firebase.js is sufficient...

Comment: Why I am getting "provider is not defined" ? any idea ?

Answer (score 8):

One common gotcha with Firebase that would cause this error is if your script loads before Firebase. When using Firebase Hosting for example they create these tags:

```
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  ...
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

You need to then also load your script using defer

```
  <script defer src="js/app.js"></script>
```