# script loads before external script even though placed last

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-chrome, firefox

i'm building a Firebase app,
so on the front end i added script tags for the fireabse app.

```
 <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "secret",
      authDomain: "secret",
      databaseURL: "https://secret.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "secret",
      storageBucket: "secret.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "secret",
      appId: "secret",
      measurementId: "secret"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
```

this is placed in the head tag.

then before the body close tag i added my own script `login.js`.

but sometimes I see in Chrome and Edge that `firebase is not defined`. in the network tab i see that `login.js` loaded fist and only then the Firebase scripts. 
in firefox it always loads `login.js` first.

I tried adding `defer` to `login.js` but doeasn't seem to help.

How can I make sure that the Firebase scripts load first?

Thank you

Comment: does this help? Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633212/firebase-is-not-defined

Comment: not sure, there's no answer there. also i use external scripts, they use bower to install the scripts locally.

Comment: i was more referring to this specific answer about how you instantiate Firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800705/3393804